# Converting File sizes from bytes to Kb or Mb

Tags: vba, excel

I have got a large amount of rows with different values in it, from 1000s to 1,000,000s.

This is data that has come across to me in bytes and i need to convert it to Kb or Mb respectively.

I could divide all the values by 1M and get all the data en Mb but i want to have the data in kb and Mb.

I tried using the MOD function but that wont do the trick as all the numbers are going to be divisible by 1K and 1M so i am a bit stuck!

here is a sample of the data that i get:

```
16000000
220000
2048000
2048000
230000
16000000
230000
16000000
220000
230000
```

so what i need is that if the cell contains 6 zeros then divide by 1M or if the cell contains 3 zeros devide by 1000.

I will add concatenation to each individual result in order to get the data differentiated.

Comment: Is that not replaing the 0's? 16000000/1000000 =16

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes, and that would be 16Mb which is what i want to be displayed on the spreadsheet, not 16M Bytes

Comment: I wouldn't actually alter the values via formula or macro. Using a custom number format is generally a better idea, it gives you more freedom and enables easier future calculations, while providing the readability needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for some VBA code you might use this Function:

```
Public Function yourFunction(ByVal number)
  If number > 1000000 Then
    'number as MB
    yourFunction = number / 1000000
    'or use the following to add MB
    'yourFunction = (number / 1000000) & " Mb"
  Else
    'number in kB
    yourFunction = number / 1000
    'or use the following to add kB
    'yourFunction = (number / 1000) & " Kb"
  End if
End Function
```

If you are looking for an Excel-Formula you might use this Function (original value in A1), put this formula in another column (for example column B)

```
=IF(A1>1000000,A1/1000000,A1/1000)
```

or with concatenation:

```
=IF(A1>1000000,CONCATENATE(A1/1000000," Mb"),CONCATENATE(A1/1000," Kb"))
```

Comment: that was it mate!.. brilliant! thanks!... all the other answers are great but yours is exactly what i had in my head but could not put into code!

Answer (score 6):

This is the function you are looking for :

```
Public Function SizeInStr(ByVal Size_Bytes As Double) As String
    Dim TS()
    ReDim TS(4)
    TS(0) = "b"
    TS(1) = "kb"
    TS(2) = "Mb"
    TS(3) = "Gb"
    TS(4) = "Tb"

Dim Size_Counter As Integer
Size_Counter = 0

    If Size_Bytes <= 1 Then
        Size_Counter = 1
    Else
        While Size_Bytes > 1
            Size_Bytes = Size_Bytes / 1000
            ''Or
            'Size_Bytes = Size_Bytes / 1024
            Size_Counter = Size_Counter + 1
        Wend
    End If

    SizeInStr = Format(Size_Bytes * 1000, "##0.0#") & " " & TS(Size_Counter - 1)
    ''Or
    'SizeInStr = Format(Size_Bytes * 1024, "##0.0#") & " " & TS(Size_Counter - 1)
End Function
```

Use it simply like this :

```
Private Sub Test_SizeInStr()
   MsgBox SizeInStr(1000000)
End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that since 1998 the IEC (practically ISO) standard for kilobytes, megabytes etc. conversion is 1000. 1024 is called kibibyte, mebibyte etc.

Comment: @vacip : Thx for that, apparently I'm already pretty old, I learned that before and didn't have the faintest clue!^^

Comment: Yeah, this was a shocking discovery for me too a few years back... The fun part is that now there is total confusion. Hardware manufacturers generally use 1000, while software engineers usually use 1024 (hence you buy a 1TB HDD, and get less (931 GB) when you pop it in your machine).

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid changing the numbers themselves, and use a number format instead. If you use a function or macro to modify the number, then you will no longer be able to eg. sum them up.

This number format does exactly what you need, but leaves the actual numbers untouched, in bytes, so you can still use them in formulas:

```
[>1000000]0,,"Mb";[>1000]0,"kb";0"b"
```

Note that this can be environment language dependent. For me with Hungarian regional settings, spaces must be used instead of commas:

```
[>1000000]0  "Mb";[>1000]0 "kb";0"b"
```

What space/comma does is each of them "hides" three digits from the end.

Answer (score 0):

For any number `n`, apply this

```
If n Mod 1000 = 0 Then
    n = n / 1000
End If
```

twice. On the first run it will convert millions to thousands, and thousands to units. On the second run it will converts any thousands to units.